# Why does Java HSQL throw an AbstractMethodError exception?

Tags: java, exception, jdbc, hsqldb

I'm getting an AbstractMethodError exception from a GIS library using HSQL. I'm guessing this is caused by a configuration issue on my machine, but I'm not sure if its related to the JRE, or some other system lib. Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcResultSet.isClosed()Z
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Something* was compiled against a version of JDBC which has the method `void isClosed()` in the `ResultSet` interface, but the version of HSQLDB available at runtime does not have that method. The most likely explanation is just that you need to update the HSQLDB lib you're using to run the app.

This method was added to the `ResultSet` interface in Java 6 (i.e., JDBC 4.0) so an older HSQLDB driver would not have it.

Comment: ok, it looks like Ubuntu has stopped releasing updates in apt-get for HSQL. The current version is 1.8.0.10.

Answer (score 0):

Pay extra attention to the fact that groupId has been changed after 1.8.0.10 release to

```
<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
  <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
```

Check maven [repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hsqldb/hsqldb/2.3.4) for details